# How find element in xdocument and read next elements after them

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

So i have next xml document:

```
<Items>
     <Item>
          <ID>123</ID>
          <Name>Super Item</Name>
          <Count>1</Count>
          <Price>45</Price>
     </Item>
     <Item>
          <ID>456</ID>
          <Name>not super Item</Name>
          <Count>10</Count>
          <Price>5</Price>
     </Item>
     <Item>
          <ID>789</ID>
          <Name>Simple Item</Name>
          <Count>6</Count>
          <Price>10</Price>
     </Item>
</Items>
```

So how can i find needed item by ID and read next values? Thanks in advance.

code:

> XDocument doc = XDocument.Load (filePath);
>
> ```
> foreach (var item in doc.Descendants("ID"))
> {
>    if ((string)item.Element("ID") == "789") 
>    {
>
>        How to read Name "Simple Item"?
>        How to read Count "6"?
>        How to read Price "10"?
>
>    }
> }
> ```

Comment: Would you mind showing your code so far? It sounds like you're asking us to just do it for you and give you the code. If you need some help getting started, I recommend looking into [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx), [XMLDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx), and/or [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx). There's loads of examples and documentation in those links, other questions just like this here on SO, and examples/tutorials elsewhere on the internet.

Comment: Please don't add code as a comment, edit your post and format it there so it's actually readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By what you are asking you could formatt your xml like this:

```
<Items>
  <Item id="123">
    <Name>Super Item</Name>
    <Count>1</Count>
    <Price>45</Price>
  </Item>
  <Item id="456">
    <Name>not super Item</Name>
    <Count>10</Count>
    <Price>5</Price>
  </Item>
  <Item id="789">
    <Name>Simple Item</Name>
    <Count>6</Count>
    <Price>10</Price>
  </Item>
</Items>
```

Then in code:

```
int yourId = 456;
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
var result = from el in doc.Root.Elements("Item")
             where el.Attribute("id").Value == yourId.ToString()
             select el;
```

The id here is an attribute.And for reading its values 2 ways:

```
//1º
foreach (var item in result.Elements())
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name + " = " + item.Value);
}

//2º - will print the element
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do when you find those values. Here is a general method using a foreach loop to find the item with the specified ID and returning it's name:

```
private string GetItemName(string _id)
{
    XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xDoc.Load("myXmlFile.xml");

    foreach (XmlNode item in xDoc.SelectNodes("/Items/Item"))
    {
        if (item.SelectSingleNode("ID").InnerText == _id)
        {
            // we found the item! Now what do we do?
            return item.SelectSingleNode("Name").InnerText;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```